# Inserting data from android application to PostgreSQL database using PHP web service issue

Tags: java, php, android, json, postgresql

I'm tearing my hair out over this problem I am having. I am trying to allow a user to upload some data from their android application to a website service which I have developed.

The data is to be uploaded using JSON and Android to a PHP web service which will then 'INSERT' the data into my PostgreSQL database.

I am unsure where the logic error is in my whole application as the app produces no errors at runtime but when I check the database records of my PostgreSQL server space there has been no data committed.

Please see below the code I am using and please try to help identify where I am going wrong. I have looked for tutorials on Google but they all are based on reading data FROM a PHP web service to an android app but I am looking to send the original data from the android app.

**DataPost Activity**

```
public void postData() throws JSONException{
       Toast.makeText(DataSummary.this, "Done! Check your profile online to see your record.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
             //Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://users.aber.ac.uk/dwd/mfb/php/jsonscript.php");
               JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

               Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), i);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
                byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, i);

               try {
                   //JSON data:
                   json.put("photo", ba1.toString());
                   json.put("name", name);
                   json.put("description", description);
                   json.put("latitude", latitude);
                   json.put("longitude", longitude);
                   json.put("project", project);
                   json.put("owner", username);

                   JSONArray postjson = new JSONArray();
                   postjson.put(json);

                   //Post the data
                   httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());
                   httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", postjson);

                   //Execute HTTP Post Request
                   System.out.println(json);
                   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                   //for JSON
                   if(response != null)
                   {
                       InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

                       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                       String line = null;
                       try{
                           while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                               sb.append(line + "\n");
                           }
                       } catch (IOException e){
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       } finally {
                           try {
                               is.close();
                           } catch(IOException e){
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                       }
                   }

               } catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
       });
       trd.start();
   }
```

**PHP Webservice**

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = pg_connect("database_string");

//VARIABLES TO BE WRITTEN TO THE DATABASE
$photo = $_REQUEST["photo"];

echo $photo;
$binary=base64_decode($photo);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

$name = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["name"]));
$safe_name = pg_escape_string($name);
$desc = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["description"]));
$safe_desc = pg_escape_string($desc);
$latitude = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["latitude"]));
$longitude = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["longitude"]));
$project = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["project"]));
$owner = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["owner"]));

$id = pg_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $owner");
$id_assoc = pg_fetch_assoc($id);
$id_res = $id_assoc['u_id'];

//SQL STATEMENT HERE FOR INSERT

$res = pg_query("INSERT INTO records (photo, name, description, latitude, longitude, project, owner) VALUES ('$photo', '$safe_name', '$safe_desc', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$project', '$id_res'");

pg_close($conn);

?>
```

Anyone who can provide some advice/tutorials/code solutions would be a hero in my book!

Comment: Maybe a stupid suggestion... but transactions? Is the `INSERT` statement committed or rolled back at `pg_close`?

Comment: would you suggest getting rid of `pg_close` and testing the submit again?

Comment: @mthmulders no success when getting rid of `pg_close();`

Comment: Don't make everyone else guess. Log your variables and log your results. That way you'll know what the problem is. Also, use proper query parameters rather than passing values blindly into an SQL statement.

Comment: My suggestion would be to add `pg_query("COMMIT");`, in order to explicitly commit your transaction.

Comment: @RichardHuxton The code doesn't pass values *blindly* into the SQL statement, since it uses `pg_escape_string`. It really should use proper parameterised statements for readability, simplicity, performance and extra paranoia, though.

Comment: @mthmulders It looks like php's Pg driver uses autocommit by default (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) so that shouldn't be necessary; there's no `BEGIN` in the code. Still a good idea since we don't know what else might be going on.

Comment: @DanielD  I think it's more likely that the problem is that **the code totally ignores the return value from `pg_query`**, performing no error checking whatsoever. *Check the PostgreSQL log files* (errors will be shown there) and *fix your code to check for and report errors*. You'll then find out what's wrong. Check for a false return value and use [`pg_last_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php) to get the error detail, as per [the documentation for `pg_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php). (P.S: Please always show PHP & Postgresql versions)

Comment: @CraigRinger - He's calling pg_escape_string once, and json_decode everywhere else. I can't see why json_decode wouldn't generate unsafe values with the correct input.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `SELECT` query return anything? I'm not a PHP expert but to me it looks like you're sending the variables wrong so there shouldn't be:

```
$id = pg_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $owner");
```

But

```
$id = pg_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ='".$owner."'");
```

Similar for the INSERT query. 
Other thoughts:

- don't do a `SELECT *` when you just want one column it will be slower. For example with index-only-scans in 9.2 you could return the id straight from the index(email,id)
- if you want to use just the id of the user it's better to put it in the subquery of the insert query
  `INSERT INTO records ( ... ,owner) VALUES (... ,(SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='".$owner."')")`
  You could even add `RETURNING owner` at the end to get the owner id out from the insert query if you need it somewhere else.

Comment: modified my SQL queries to your suggestions but still no success :(

Comment: @DanielD you haven't answered if the `SELECT` returns the right thing or not.